# Why does the Discord.js Boiler Plate Bot not work?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm starting to code a Discord bot, and I'm using the basic boiler plate code that is give on the [Discord.js Home Page](https://discord.js.org/#/) which is this -

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work. And yes, I replaced the token with the Bot Token. When I start it, it doesn't respond for a few seconds, and then this error pops up in the debugger. (I'm using nodemon)

```
(node:14931) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AbortError: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/sulphurouscerebrum/Projects/Discord Bot/Sulph Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:93:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:14931) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:14931) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Discord.js but to no avail. Could someone tell me what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request took longer than the specified `restRequestTimeout` (15 seconds by default) and was aborted to not lock up the request handler. It can be an internal server error on Discord's side or just a slow connection. In the case of the latter, the `restRequestTimeout` option in [`ClientOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions) can be increased to prevent future `AbortErrors`.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ restRequestTimeout: 30000 }); // 30s
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an error happening within the discord.js library when a web request is stuck for a long time, which might happen due to an outage or bad internet connection. It can be ignored since it doesn't kill the program, but you can try to put your code in a try/catch statement to avoid it.